# OutOfMemory on big HTTP MultipartRequestEntity via apache HttpClient 3.1

Tags: java, http, out-of-memory, httpclient, multipart

I'm actually trying to upload a file (>5M) using apache HttpClient 3.1 via MultipartRequestEntity with java 1.4 in a low memory environment, so increasing java heap is not possible

I have a file splitted in many parts, I just need to append all the data of each part into the request, I could get the file without splitting too

The real problem is that the request I'm building, is producing the memory to overflow, is there any way to avoid this and be able to send this request at once?

This is what I actually have, I would need to append the bytes to the part (a kind of part[0].write(data)), or get a stream to write it without loading into the memory, I don't know if it is actually possible

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);

    post.setContentChunked(true);

    try {
        Part[] parts = new Part[fileNames.size()];

        String fileName = "sample.pdf";

        for(int i = 0; i<fileNames.size();i++){
            File file = Util.getFile(fileNames.get(i));
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            parts[i] = new FilePart("file", new ByteArrayPartSource(fileName, fileBytes) , "application/octet-stream", post.getRequestCharSet()); 
            is.close();
            is = null;
            fileBytes = null;
        }

     MultipartRequestEntity requestEntity = new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, post.getParams());

     post.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);


     int statusCode = client.executeMethod(post);
```

Another possibility is with HttpUrlConnection writing a BufferedWriter, but this will also give OutOfMemory when writing on it

Comment: The HTTP Performance Client website is worth reading... http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html

Comment: could you please be more specific? I already checked its website, Maybe I'm not explaining myself correctly, I will edit my answer in order to not confuse

Comment: The trick is not to build up the whole request in memory. I don't know if you can do that with the Apache client (never used that) but you can certainly do it by using the raw HttpConnection.

Comment: I've seen a method in HttpConnection called setFixedLengthStreamingMode, I guess that's what you are talking about but it is specified for java 1.5 and above

Comment: you build your own request entity.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but the problem I see here is the Part (FilePart) itself, it does not allow to be written more than one time. The lack of code examples leaves me without ideas, I'm still looking how to do it, I've been able to do it if I send the file directly, but I'm not sure if I'm able to do it in the real environment, I will try it and edit my question if I success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could have done this with File java file class directly, but the problem was that I have not a java File class, instead I had to implement PartSource to read my special file class and set it to read after joining all of my file parts in one single file obligatorily.
Usually you should do this:

```
parts[0] = new FilePart("file", new FilePartSource(file) , "application/octet-stream", postMethod.getRequestCharSet());
```

You need a File if you don't want to get the whole data buffered in memory for the request

Now I have this solved